# I am trying to find the roots of my equation but I am getting an error that "numpy.ndarray" object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the roots of my equation but I am getting an error that :

```
"numpy.ndarray" object is not callable
```

my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

q = (3 * np.sin(t / np.sqrt(2))) - (np.sin(t))

root = fsolve(q, 4)
print(root)
```

Comment: Did you try a `print(q)`?  What is `t`?  Does this `q` match the `fsolve` doc specification?

Comment: t was just a numpy array of numbers between certain period.  And I did not try to print(q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use [`from scipy.optimize import fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html), You need write `q` as `function`.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(x):
    return (3 * np.sin(t / np.sqrt(2))) - (np.sin(t))


root = fsolve(func, 1)
print(root)
```